# Assigning anonymous functions to function-pointer methods in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a simple CPU simulator.

The `CPU` class has a `hash_map<uint8_t, Instruction> instructionTable;` and within the `CPU` constructor I would like to create all the `Instruction` objects and insert them into `instructionTable`.

#### Instruction.h:

```
#ifndef INSTRUCTION_H
#define INSTRUCTION_H
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include "CPU.h"

class Instruction
{
public:
    uint8_t opcode;

    Instruction();    
    void(*execute)(CPU* cpu);    
};

#endif
```

#### CPU.h:

```
#ifndef CPU_H
#define CPU_H
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Instruction.h"
#include "Memory.h"

class CPU
{
public:
    Memory* memory;

    CPU(Memory* memory);        
    void loadInstructionSet();

};

#endif
```

#### CPU.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CPU.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

CPU::CPU(Memory* memory){      
    this->memory = memory;
}

void CPU::loadInstructionSet(){
    Instruction *LDA = new Instruction();
    LDA->execute = [](CPU*) { std::cout << "execute LDA..."; };       
}
```

How can I now create `Instruction` objects and assign a new execute function?

I thought lambda expressions / anonymous functions are used for such things.

Comment: Lambda expression is of `std::function<R(A)>` type, where R stands for lambda's return type and A stands for lambda's argument list.

Comment: FYI, hash_map is not standard C++. See [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Thank you guys. I tried changing the function pointer inside the Instruction Class to a `std::function<void(CPU*)>` but that doesn't compile. When I remove the argument or change it to `string` for example, then it works. But I need to pass a CPU pointer to the function.

Comment: @Alvarey That is wrong (in C++). Lambda-expressions are of a unique class type, unrelated to `std::function`. The latter is a *function wrapper* with a misleading name.

Comment: @dyp Ye, you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This line:

   ```
   void *(execute)(CPU* cpu);
   ```

   is a *function declaration*. To declare a *function pointer*, use

   ```
   void (*execute)(CPU* cpu);
   ```
2. > Cannot convert from `void` to `void (__cdecl *)(void)`

   This is because you call your lambda, and its return expression is absent i.e. equals to void. Remove last bracket:

   ```
   LDA->execute = []() { cout << "execute LDA..."; };
   ```
3. Note also that [a lambda can only be converted to a function pointer if it does not capture](/a/28746827/1823963).

   Prefer to use `std::function` instead of raw function pointers.

Comment: Using `std::function` instead of raw pointers is not always a better solution. `std::function` is more flexible, because it allows to store stateful "functions", but it is also more heavyweight.

Comment: Yep, `std::function` is known to have an allocation overhead with some combinations of the C++ compiler and library.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your changes but now get the following two errors:
1) error C2061: Syntaxerror : Type 'CPU' 

2) error C2440: cannot convert from 'CPU::loadInstructionSet::<lambda_574d353bed5e0ee83664ce255e8c8e4d>'  to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' k

I updated and posted the complete code in my post on the top

Comment: Very strange. I finished your code, and it has started.

Answer (score 3):

> LDA->execute =  { cout << "execute LDA..."; }();

This should be

```
LDA->execute = [](CPU*) { cout << "execute LDA..."; };
```

First, with the brackets at the end of the line you're actually calling the lambda right after creating it.

Second, the type definition of `execute` says that the function expects a pointer to `CPU`, but in the lambda you take the `CPU` by value and not by a pointer.